# MuleSoft: share custom component offline

Tags: mule, mule-component

I would like to build a custom component and share it with my team. I don't want to online upload the new component. Is there an offline way to share components?

I can define my github account instead of Mule's when creating a project. Will then it be private?

Adding details:

I created jars which I want to use in my Mule project. I added 2 Java classes in my project that uses the jars. I also have 3 apps on different computers that needs the jars. 
Instead of duplicating these jars and the Java code, I would like to wrap it in a component/ connector and share the component between apps/developers in my team. As far as I understood from reading I can use both connector and component for my needs. However, I couldn't understand how can I share offline what I built.

Comment: Is this question about Mule ESB? What do you mean by component: a custom Java class that implements/extends Mule?

Comment: Yes, this is a question about Mule ESB. I added more details to my question and hopefully it will clarify my needs.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to Maven-deploy your common JARs to a private Maven repository. This can be a simple as an S3 bucket or as refined as [Nexus server](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/go/).

This way, your different Mule projects will be able to pull these common JARs in their builds by simply adding them to their `pom.xml` files.